# How to get timestamps correspond to the current days date? With Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The number of rows in the A table, where the date value of the timestamps in the [time_created] and / or `[time_updated]` fields correspond to the current day's date

Comment: Can you show some sample input and output ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CONVERT()` function.

```
CONVERT(date, YOUR-COL-NAME-HERE)
```

So if you are looking for rows with today's date, you should have something like:

```
WHERE CONVERT(date, YOUR-COL-NAME-HERE) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
```

Comment: it must be and/or, not  only and

Comment: You have been given the basic guidance, do not expect us to write the code for you...

Answer (score 0):

[`GETDATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql) returns the current date as a `datetime`. You can use `convert` to extract the date part from it:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE()) IN
       (CONVERT(DATE, time_created), CONVERT(DATE, time_updated))
```

Comment: @anna the `in` operator is a shorthand for a series of `or`s, it should have the required functionality.